# Sorting two columns with sort and uniq

Tags: text-processing, sort, uniq

I have a file that needs sorting in a specific way but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried the following command but it doesn't give me what I want:

```
sort -t" " -k1,1 Original_File | uniq -d > Desired_Output
```

Original_File:

```
User1 US
User1 NG
User2 US
User3 US
User4 US
User4 EN
User5 US
```

Desired_Output:

```
User1 US
User1 NG
User4 US
User4 EN
```

Comment: What's the complete desired output?

Comment: Exactly what I put. I want it to show if a "User" has two country codes and then output the users that do.

Comment: So actually you want to find repeated occurrences of User 1?

Comment: @KasiyA other than having the words `User3 US`, and being asked by him, it is not duplicated in any way. `How to find the difference between...` is totally different to `How to find duplicates from a file`.

Comment: @Tim Ok you are right[edited question]. I have deleted above comment.

Comment: Is the order of `User4 US` and `User4 EN` important? Could `User4 US` be the last line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the first column, pick up the duplicates, and grep them back from the file again:

```
cut -f1 -d' ' Original_File | sort | uniq -d | grep -wFf- Original_File
```

Comment: What does the -wf- do in grep? I know capital 'F' is fgrep

Comment: `-w` is `force PATTERN to match only whole words` and `-f` is `obtain PATTERN from FILE`. Just there under `grep --help`

Comment: `w` works for whole words (so User1 doesn't select User11), and `f-` tells grep to read the patterns from the file `-`, which is stdin.

Comment: This gives me exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

*The example input and output was updated; the examples in the first section use the original example input to show detail examples on variants:*

Original input in `Original_File`:

```
User1 US
User1 NG
User2 US
User3 US
User4 US
User5 US
```

---

You can skip the `userN` part for `uniq` with the option `-f` to skip leading fields - separated by space:

```
$ sort -t" " -k1,1 Original_File | uniq -f 1 
User1 NG
User1 US
```

For the same order as in the example output, you can reverse the sort - this will change the "label" values of the unique lines:

```
$ sort -r -t" " -k1,1 Original_File | uniq -f 1
User5 US
User1 NG
```

Note the `User5` in the first result line. If that's not acceptable, just sort again:

```
$ sort -t" " -k1,1 Original_File | uniq -f 1 | sort  -t" " -k1,1 -r
User1 US
User1 NG
```

If the `UserN` part is not separated by space, but has a fixed length, you can skip it for `uniq` with the option `-s`:

```
$ sort -t" " -k1,1 Original_File | uniq -s 6
User1 NG
User1 US
```

---

With the updated example input, this is the command for creating the required sort order:

```
$ sort -t" " -k1,1 Original_File | uniq -f 1 | sort -t" " -k1,1  -k2,2r
User1 US
User1 NG
User4 US
User4 EN
```

it sorts the second field to reverse order.

Comment: Just pipped me to the post! About to answer that the same way.

Comment: Nearly, but he doesn't want it reversed, he wants it same order as the original. I have edited to clarify.

Comment: Hmm... I do not see where he specifies that?

Comment: He doesn't, but I think it is a reasonable assumption that there will be multiple languages.